# Calculate multivariable equation with python

Tags: python, math, curve-fitting, equation, adc

I am trying to calculate the voltage of a circuit with an ADC, the problem is that I am seeing that the voltage reading has to be done from a function and that it depends on the current of the circuit, I arrived at the following equations for 0A, 0.4 A and 1.1A:

0A:     0.10680454x - 7.6688459

0.4A:   0.10669344x - 13.84042838

1.1A:   0.10652463x - 24.9126498

How can I put this together into an equation with two variables One for the voltage reading and one for the amperage.
Preferably in python.

Thank you so much!

Here is a plot of how the amperaje affects the votlage reading

[image: Plot of how aperaje affect voltage reading]

Comment: Hi. Could you please label the axes?

Comment: The python part shouldn't be that hard but I personally would need more info to help you.
So you need a function ´ADC=fun(Amp, Vol)´ that contains a formula ´ADC = ax+b´ with x beeing the voltage and a&b depending on the ampere?
To calculate ´a&b´ should we assume a linear relationship?  If it's the case, I can only approximate with the datas you gave us. This would be nice if you have more :)

Comment: Other question: if a take the first value for 0A: 0.10680454x - 7.6688459 with x = 200, the result is 13.69206... In your graph, this is appr. 1900. Do I miss something? How did you get this graph?

Comment: Those functions are effectively all the same function with the same slope but a different x-intercept. So first scale your `x` based on amps, then plug it into the _single_ function for voltage.